# What css do I need to keep text in vertical position?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my reactjs app. one component will show/hide a div by changing a stateproperty. The style for this component will change depending on these cssrules(open/close):

```
.open {
    display: block;
}

.close {
    display:none;
}
.rela {
    position: relative;
}
```

reactjs code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class Hero extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.state = { open: false }
    }

    toggle() {
        console.log('toggle');
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
        console.log(this.state.open);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="rela">
                <Button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>Click this</Button>
                <div className={this.state.open ? 'open' : 'close'}>
                    show me
               </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Hero;
```

Under this component there is another component with some text. At the moment this text is pushed down once the other component is displayed(open). What css do I need to keep this text in the same position vertically? The css for this component is:

```
.stuff {
        z-index: 1064;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        background-color: #e2f1fc;
        padding-top: 7px;   
    }
```

reactjs code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Kid extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
              <div className="stuff">
                   some text : dont push me down
               </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Kid;
```

Comment: I don't want to rotate the text or anything, just keep the bottom component text in the same position, ie without pushing it down.

Comment: have you tried using z-index and position to add the text either on top or below text? If it's stacked, it shouldn't mess with anything around it

Comment: @Keith yes I did see code above.

Comment: is the parent fixed as well? z-index won't work if the position's aren't matching